# I want to assign width of div with document.ready() but unable to do so?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, document-ready

Trying this code , but not working :

```
$(document).onload(function () {
    var wid = $(window).width();
    var hdsize = wid / 16 + " em";
    $("#hd").css("width", hdsize);
});
```

Instead it loads pre-fed values.

Answer (score 3):

Should be:

```
$(window).load(function () {...});
```

`document` doesn't fire `onload`, which in jQuery is `load`, hence `window` instead `document`.

If you need only to wait until `document` has been parsed, you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {...});
```

And as Hugo has stated in his comment, you need to remove the space from the unit:

`var hdsize = wid / 16 + "em";`.

Comment: if this does'n solve your problem... try to remove the space from `" em"`.. put just `"em"`

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes You're absolutely right, units should appear immediately after value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    var wid = $(window).width();
    var hdsize = wid / 16;
    $("#hd").css("width", hdsize +" em");

 });
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful.